# Tracking mp3 plays/downloads through XML file

Tags: xml, google-analytics, adobe-analytics

I have an XML file, which I host on my website, that has links to about 100 mp3 files that I host on my website. I push this XML file to iTunes and to my app. There are some direct links to the files on my site's pages, but for the most part, users access the files via iTunes or the app.

However, after many hours of research, I still cannot figure out how to track plays to individual mp3s. In order to play one of the files, the user needs to load the XML file (through iTunes or through the app) and then the XML file plays the file that's hosted on my website.

I have Google Analytics and Adobe Analytics set up for my site. However, I cannot figure out a way to send this information to them.

I'm thinking this could involve some sort of tracking tag in the XML file. Do you have any ideas, even to just point me in the right direction? Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're going to have to implement a server-side solution that sends the data using a [Data Source](http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/analytics/data-sources-inside-omniture-sitecatalyst/) for Adobe Analytics and [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide) for Google Analytics.

One way is to write a server-side script that parses your server request log file for the mp3 request entries. The script should be on a cron job. Note that according to the [Queue Time entry](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) in the GA doc, you may start to run into trouble if you attempt to submit offline data that's more than 4 hours old, so be sure to set your cron job to execute accordingly.

Alternative to the server log file parsing - it may be worth having your server route requests to the mp3 files to a single controller script (e.g. using mod rewrite) that makes the requests to the Analytics servers and then serves up the mp3 file. This would be somewhat simpler than parsing the server log file and will allow for real-time collection but it may or may not be worth it depending on how much traffic you get from this (because of load on your server).

A compromise between the two might be to have the controller script simply log to a separate file or db and then serve up the mp3 file and then have a separate script process that.  This way you won't have to parse the general server request log for a bunch of file entries. This method would also have a script on a cron job.

Comment: The second option is what we've done in the past. We don't directly serve the files but send them to a clean url -- domain.com/fileName etc. Our server would either run the php/java library for tracking, sometimes the javascript before returning the actual file. Checkout the data insertion libraries @ https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/en_US/documentation/data-insertion/c-sample-code